# Carousel : Y-axis with numbers not displayed on slide change

Tags: html, charts, google-visualization, carousel

I have added charts onto carousel, problem is charts does not show y-axis with numbers, it shows only on load, on slide change it`s not displaying, I tried changing colors, reduced width, but not coming at all.

HTML Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .carousel-indicators li {
        background-color: #BFC9CA ;
      }
      .carousel-indicators .active {
        background-color: #BFC9CA ;
      }
      h3
      {
      background-color: gold ;
      }
      .carousel-inner {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 500px ;
    }
    .carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
    </style>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });</script>
    <script language='JavaScript'>function drawChart(PassCount, FailCount, DivID) { var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Status', 'Outcome', { role: 'style' }], ['Passed', PassCount, '#8BC34A'], ['Failed', FailCount, '#ff4c4c']]); var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(data, [{ column: 0, modifier: function () { return 'total' }, type: 'string' }], [{ column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number' }]); var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '#,##0.0%' }); var formatShort = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: 'short' }); var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, { calc: function (dt, row) { var amount = formatShort.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1)); var percent = formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) / groupData.getValue(0, 1)); return amount + ' (' + percent + ')'; }, type: 'string', role: 'annotation' }]); var options = { 'legend': 'none', tooltip: { trigger: 'none' }, 'width': 650, 'height': 400, animation: { duration: 1500, startup: true } }; var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(DivID)); chart.draw(view, options); } google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () { drawChart(70, 5, 'GoogleColChart_0'); }); google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () { drawChart(80, 10, 'GoogleColChart_1'); }); google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () { drawChart(90, 15, 'GoogleColChart_2'); });</script>
    <link rel='icon' type='Icon.ico' href='Icon.ico' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div align="center" class="item active">
            <div id='GoogleColChart_0' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'>
              <script type='text/javascript'>drawChart(70, 5, 'GoogleColChart_0');</script>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div align="center" class="item">
            <div id='GoogleColChart_1' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'>
              <script type='text/javascript'>drawChart(80, 10, 'GoogleColChart_1');</script>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div align="center" class="item">
            <div id='GoogleColChart_2' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'>
              <script type='text/javascript'>drawChart(90, 15, 'GoogleColChart_2');</script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Charts should be displayed with y-axis values even on slide change too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cannot draw charts in a hidden container.
the chart cannot properly calculate the placement of all the chart elements.
need to wait until the chart is shown before drawing for the first time...

first, only need to draw the first chart when the page is first displayed.
remove the following lines (assuming `GoogleColChart_0` is shown first by default)...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () { drawChart(80, 10, 'GoogleColChart_1'); });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () { drawChart(90, 15, 'GoogleColChart_2'); });
```

next, remove the `<script>` tags inside the chart `<div>` elements.
and add the pass / fail counts as data attributes.

```
<div data-pass="70" data-fail="5" id='GoogleColChart_0' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'></div>
```

add add a new `<script>` tag as the last tag before the end of the body `</body>`,
to listen for the carousel's *slid* event.
when the *slid* event fires, draw the chart that is shown,
passing in the values from the data attributes...

```
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (sender) {
    // draw chart that is shown
    var container = $(sender.relatedTarget).find('div');
    drawChart(container.data('pass'), container.data('fail'), container.prop('id'));
  });
```

---

see following working snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      .carousel-indicators li {
        background-color: #BFC9CA ;
      }
      .carousel-indicators .active {
        background-color: #BFC9CA ;
      }
      h3
      {
      background-color: gold ;
      }
      .carousel-inner {
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 500px ;
    }
    .carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
    </style>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });</script>
    <script language='JavaScript'>function drawChart(PassCount, FailCount, DivID) { var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Status', 'Outcome', { role: 'style' }], ['Passed', PassCount, '#8BC34A'], ['Failed', FailCount, '#ff4c4c']]); var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(data, [{ column: 0, modifier: function () { return 'total' }, type: 'string' }], [{ column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number' }]); var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: '#,##0.0%' }); var formatShort = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: 'short' }); var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, { calc: function (dt, row) { var amount = formatShort.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1)); var percent = formatPercent.formatValue(dt.getValue(row, 1) / groupData.getValue(0, 1)); return amount + ' (' + percent + ')'; }, type: 'string', role: 'annotation' }]); var options = { 'legend': 'none', tooltip: { trigger: 'none' }, 'width': 650, 'height': 400, animation: { duration: 1500, startup: true } }; var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(DivID)); chart.draw(view, options); } google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () { drawChart(70, 5, 'GoogleColChart_0'); });</script>
    <link rel='icon' type='Icon.ico' href='Icon.ico' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div align="center" class="item active">
            <div data-pass="70" data-fail="5" id='GoogleColChart_0' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div align="center" class="item">
            <div data-pass="80" data-fail="10" id='GoogleColChart_1' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'></div>
          </div>
          <div align="center" class="item">
            <div data-pass="90" data-fail="15" id='GoogleColChart_2' style='width:800; height:500;border-style:groove;border-width: 1px;'></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (sender) {
        // draw chart that is shown
        var container = $(sender.relatedTarget).find('div');
        drawChart(container.data('pass'), container.data('fail'), container.prop('id'));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made the above changes, getting error 'Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×' when it moves to second slide.

Comment: I put an alert in the drawChart function, for the second slide the values are not right, I separated params by ':', I got 'NaN:NaN:myCarousel' as an alert.

Comment: Neither worked, getting 'Uncaught Error: Container is not defined' error.

Comment: Nope. When I sent sender, the alert says undefined. Can`t you use jsfiddle or some other tool?

Comment: Yes! Sender`s been included.